# launchpad build fails, but pbuilder works

Tags: package-management, ppa

This is my first attempt with .deb packaging for a very long time, so it's likely to be a stupid mistake. That said, as heading says: my package builds fine in pbuilder on a trusty 14.04.3 host, but fails on launchpad. FWIW, my gut feeling is that the installation has placed the files in different places.

This is based on a debian (jessie) build which was fine. I had to tweak a few dependencies and installation paths, but with those fixes it builds in pbuilder.

First question: What are the possible difference between building in pbuilder and on launchpad? Build environment? If so, how do I get a identical one in pbuilder?

And, of course, any hint why it fail is appreciated... The build logs are in
https://launchpad.net/~leamas-alec/+archive/ubuntu/lirc-preview/+build/8102298/+files/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-amd64.lirc_0.9.3-1.9_BUILDING.txt.gz

Comment: Found some new hints and re-generated the pbuilder using "pbuilder create --debootstrapopts --variant=buildd" and "pbuilder update  --components 'main universe' --override-config". Still, it works OK while the launchpad build fails.

Comment: This should be about the rules file, right? Available at http://ur1.ca/nytgt The offending directory etc/lirc is the first line in debian/install

Comment: The mystery is simpler, but still... It just doesn't execute 'make install' i (i. e., override_dh_auto_install) on the launchpad builder.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the proper solution but it works, sort of. Adding explicit depends on the install target in binary makes the trick. However, the install target *is* part of the sequence, so this is some kind of abomination. And, it's *not* required in pbuilder.

```
-override_dh_auto_install:
+override_dh_auto_install: debian/tmp/etc/lirc/lircd.conf
+debian/tmp/etc/lirc/lircd.conf:
     dh_testdir
     dh_testroot
@@ -46,5 +47,5 @@

# Build architecture-independent files here.
-binary-indep:
+binary-indep: debian/tmp/etc/lirc/lircd.conf
# Use system library instead of bundled jquery.js (symlinked below).
echo INSTALL TREE
@@ -67,6 +68,8 @@

 # Build architecture-dependent files here.    
-binary-arch:
+binary-arch: debian/tmp/etc/lirc/lircd.conf
    echo PWD: $$PWD
+   echo INSTALL TREE
+   tree -L 4 debian
```